How to add (and use) a secondary y axis with subplot_mosaic?
I'm setting up a somewhat elaborate plot (should end up as a pdf page at the end) and for that subplot_mosaic seems like a great solution and very straightforward with plotting into the various boxes.
However, I need two y axes in one of the plots and I can't figure out how.
MWE:
fig = plt.figure(layout='constrained')
ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic("""A.B
                                CCC
                                CCC
                                DDD""")
ax_dict['C'].plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])
ax_dict['C'].plot([1,2,3],[200,190,180])

(I've added a bunch of empty plots to show the general Idea.)
Now, obviously, plotting two different datasets into C isn't going to work without a secondary y axis. On a short search secondary_yaxis seems to be what I'm looking for and Adding the line ax_dict['C'].secondary_yaxis('right') into the MWE adds a secondary axis, but I can't figure out how to make it aware that i belongs to one of the plotted datasets. The functions part looks like I can't simply feed data that already exists into it, and apparently, This method is experimental as of 3.1, and the API may change.
Essentially, I'm looking for something like secondary_y=True, as it exists in pandas.

ax2 = ax_dict['C'].twinx(), ax2.plot(...).

I've played around with ax, since this is how I did it before, but, finding mosaic, I had really high hopes to not have to bother with this weird stuff, since I never seem to get how the hell it works. Can you post that as an answer?

I'd prefer that this be closed as a duplicate, since the linked thread covers this.

It does cover it, but there's some differences that arise from mosaic, so my previous ways didn't work, leading to this question.

ax_dict['C'] is an Axes, no difference there. Whether the Axes is created using subplots or subplot_mosaic isn't really relevant.
